# Crafty - How to get the id of the collision element?

Tags: collision-detection, crafty, entities

As the topic says, I want to know how to get the ID of an active colliding entity.

My Player Entity is called with

```
Crafty.e("Player")
```

Please notice, that I **do not want** the ID of my **Player Entity**.
I want the ID of the **Collision element**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the id of the entity your player collided with?

```
var mobs = this.hit('Mob');
if (mobs) {
    // mobs is an array, could be more than one
    var collidingMob = mobs[0].obj;

    // if you still want the crafty id of this entity
    var mobId = collidingMob[0];
}
```

Comment: Hm, if i call the "mobId" per alert, nothing useful is returned.. Its just [object Object]

Comment: So, if i use this method on "this" it's working:

alert(this.getid())

Comment: Firstly, don't use alert, use console.log().  Then you can see the object itself in your console.  Second, "this" in this context is your player, or the entity you are using to test collision.  Not the entity you collided with.  Third, using your method you would want collidingMob.getId() to get the crafty id of the entity you collided with.

Comment: Perhaps you need to know that I'm using the TiledMapBuilder.js component

Comment: Ahh, that is probably the cause of our confusion.  Sorry I know nothing about that component.  Please include important information like that in your question.